# Arduino void loop only running once

Tags: arduino

The void loop is only running once. Please help. I am inexperienced with Arduino, so any help is much-appreciated. When I open the serial monitor I only see zero once. This code was working earlier today. Sorry if the solution is very simple. Some code has been removed to fit within post restrictions such as ints and ultrasonic declarations and includes.

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); //sets up Serial monitor
  InfraredSeeker::Initialize();
}

void loop() {
  if(u = 1) {
    ang = uang;
  } else{
    ang = irang;
  }
  Serial.println(uang);
  m1 = 200*cos((30-ang)*0.0174533);
  m2 = 200*cos((270-ang)*0.0174533);
  m3 = 200*cos((150-ang)*0.0174533);
  InfraredResult InfraredBall = InfraredSeeker::ReadAC();
  switch (InfraredBall.Direction) {
  case 1:
    irang = 160;
    break;
  case 2:
    irang = 120;
    break;
  case 3:
    irang = 90;
    break;
  case 4:
    irang = 50;
    break;
  case 5:
    irang = 0;
    break;
  case 6:
    irang = 310;
    break;
  case 7:
    irang = 270;
    break;
  case 8:
    irang = 240;
    break;
  case 9:
    irang = 200;
    break;
  case 0:
    irang = 160;
    break;
  default: 
    break;
  }
  lultra = uleft.Ranging(CM);
  rultra = urigth.Ranging(CM);
  fultra = ufront.Ranging(CM);
  if (lultra < 15){
    u = 1;
    uang = 270;
  }
  if (rultra < 15) {
    u = 1;
    uang = 90;
  }
  if (fultra < 15) {
    u = 1; 
    uang = 180;
  }
}
```

Comment: You should print output in a few other spots to see where it's stopping - but my guess is that it stops on `InfraredSeeker::ReadAC();` because your sensor is no longer working or a wire has fallen out etc.

Comment: Jep your loop depends totally on `ReadAC()`'s behaviour. I would implement some error handling there.

Comment: if(u = 1) should be if( u == 1) at the very top of loop